# Access first default parameter value while supplying the rest

Tags: scala, default-value

Given:

```
case class Person(name:String = "Bob", age:Int = 20)
```

How can I accept the default value for name while supplying the age?

Eg. I can do this:

```
Person() -> Person("Bob", 20)

Person("Jim") -> Person("Jim", 20)
```

How can I do this:

```
Person(,35) -> Person("Bob", 35)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use named parameters with default values:

```
case class Person(name: String = "Bob", age: Int = 20)

Person(age = 23)
```